# How to implement a nested route with a dynamic route?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router, react-router-dom

All pages are being rendered in `localhost/1`, `localhost/2`, `localhost/3`, etc.

After the user select a card to show details, the url changes to `localhost/info/:id`, this id is the id from an array.

The page with the card details let's say is `localhost/info/1`, everything look good. The problem is that inside of this page there is another link to be clicked.

If this bottom is clicked, the url should change to `localhost/info/1/episodes` and this new component should be rendered with the others details from the card.

How can I correctly implement this feature to render two components together? I'm still learning React Router.

All Routes.tsx

```
import Home from "../pages/Home";
import CharacterInfo from "../pages/CharacterInfo";
import { Route, Routes, Navigate } from "react-router-dom";
import Episodes from "../pages/Episodes";

const AllRoutes = () => {
  return (
    <Routes>
      <Route path="/" element={<Navigate to="/1" />} />
      <Route path="/info">
        <Route path=":id" element={<CharacterInfo />}>
          <Route path="/info/:id/episodes" element={<Episodes />} />
        </Route>
      </Route>
      <Route path="/:p" element={<Home />} />
      <Route path="*" element={<Home />} />
    </Routes>
  );
};

export default AllRoutes;
```

CharacterInfo.tsx

```
import { useContext, useEffect } from "react";
import { useParams, Routes, Route, Link, useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import { GetACharacterContext } from "../contexts/GetACharacterContext";
import Episodes from "./Episodes";

const CharacterInfo = () => {
  const { characterDetail, setId } = useContext(GetACharacterContext);
  const { id } = useParams();
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  useEffect(() => {
    setId(Number(id));
  }, [id]);

  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={() => navigate("/1")}>Home</button>
      <p>{characterDetail.id}</p>
      <p>{characterDetail.name}</p>
      <p>{characterDetail.age ? characterDetail.age : "No data"}</p>
      <p>{characterDetail.occupation}</p>
      <Link to={`/info/${characterDetail.id}/episodes`}>Episodes</Link>
    </>
  );
};

export default CharacterInfo;
```

Episodes.tsx

```
const Episodes = () => {
  return <div>Episodes</div>;
};

export default Episodes;
```

Comment: You want `CharacterInfo` and `Episodes` rendered together? Or separate/independent.

Comment: @DrewReese together

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`CharacterInfo` needs to render an `Outlet` component for the nested routes it's rendering, and the path needs to be relative from the parent route.

Example:

```
const AllRoutes = () => {
  return (
    <Routes>
      <Route path="/" element={<Navigate to="/1" />} />
      <Route path="/info">                                 // "/info"
        <Route path=":id" element={<CharacterInfo />}>     // "/info/:id"
          <Route path="episodes" element={<Episodes />} /> // "/info/:id/episodes"
        </Route>
      </Route>
      <Route path="/:p" element={<Home />} />
      <Route path="*" element={<Home />} />
    </Routes>
  );
};
```

...

```
const CharacterInfo = () => {
  const { characterDetail, setId } = useContext(GetACharacterContext);
  const { id } = useParams();
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  useEffect(() => {
    setId(Number(id));
  }, [id]);

  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={() => navigate("/1")}>Home</button>
      <p>{characterDetail.id}</p>
      <p>{characterDetail.name}</p>
      <p>{characterDetail.age ? characterDetail.age : "No data"}</p>
      <p>{characterDetail.occupation}</p>
      <Link to={`/info/${characterDetail.id}/episodes`}>Episodes</Link>
      <Outlet /> // <-- nested routes render content here
    </>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try it like this:

```
<Routes>
  <Route path="/" element={<Navigate to="/1" />} />
  <Route path="/info/:id" element={<CharacterInfo />} />
  <Route path="/info/:id/episodes" element={<Episodes />} />
</Routes>
```